# How to use bulma carousel with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, bulma

I downloaded bulma-carousel with NPM. I have tried googling and looking at other answers from various forum to no avail.

my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bulma-carousel.min.css">
    <!-- <script src="~bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script> -->
    <title>GIS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var carousels = bulmaCarousel.attach(); // carousels now contains an array of all Carousel instances
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my **carousel** component file

```
import React from 'react';
import bulmaCarousel from 'bulma-carousel';


class Pictures extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var carousels = bulmaCarousel.attach('.carousel', {
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            slidesToShow: 3
        });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class='carousel carousel-animated carousel-animate-slide'>
                    <div class='carousel-container'>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background is-active'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Merry Christmas</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/singer.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Original Gift: Offer a song with <a href="https://lasongbox.com" target="_blank">La Song Box</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/sushi.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Sushi time</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pictures
```

The Picture component is then exported to my App component through other components.

My page just looks like a bunch of pictures stack on top of each other. I did install bulma framework before i downloaded the bulma-carousel and use classes like Hero and columns successfully, so there isn't a problem there. I didnt download bulma-extension because i dont need all of them. Im unsure of where to put/use the bulma-carousel js, so i put them everywhere to see if it changes but it didn't

Im also new to reactjs, so forgive me if there are other things are wrong besides the carousel

Comment: Does the console throws something? Maybe try another version of bulma-carousel.  Try 4.0.1 or 3.0.0

Comment: @NicoDiz even if i did use another version, i still need guidance on how to incorporate bulma-carousel properly on my project, like which syntax goes to which file. I'm still confuse on that part as well.

Comment: You may need to use bulmaCarousel.attach() in componentDidMount(). Refer https://github.com/Wikiki/bulma-carousel/issues/30

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to attach your carousel too early. Update your component to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import bulmaCarousel from 'bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js';


class Pictures extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    componentDidMount() {
      var carousels = bulmaCarousel.attach('.carousel', {
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1
      });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class='carousel carousel-animated carousel-animate-slide'>
                    <div class='carousel-container'>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background is-active'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Merry Christmas</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/singer.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Original Gift: Offer a song with <a href="https://lasongbox.com" target="_blank">La Song Box</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='carousel-item has-background'>
                            <img class="is-background" src="https://wikiki.github.io/images/sushi.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="310" />
                            <div class="title">Sushi time</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pictures
```